# Duality of the convolution theorem in Fourier Domain

Tags: fourier-transform, hadamard-product

Convolution in the time domain can be represented as a Hadamard (pointwise) product in the Frequency domain. Using the instructions specified at 
https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38066-difference-between-conv-ifft-fft-when-doing-convolution
I am able to obtain a convolution between two vectors both in the time and frequency domain. Now, I would like to do the reverse operation.
Suppose (Using Matlab/Octave notation)

$a=[1, 2, 3, 4]$ and $b=[7, 5, 3, 1]$; Then

$c = a.*b = [7, 10, 6, 4]$. 
If I take a Fourier transform of this vector, I obtain

$c_{fft} = [34 +  0i,   -2 -  2i,   -2 +  0i,   -2 +  2i]$.

Now, If I apply the duality property of convolution,

$c_{fft} = conv(FFT(a),FFT(b))$ should be true (as Hadamard multiplication in time domain is equivalent to convolution in Fourier domain). However, when I implement the same, I get the following:

$c_{fft} = [224 +   0i,    24 +  40i,   -24 +  32i,    -8 +   8i,   -88 +   0i,   -32 -  48i,    16 -  32i]$

Am I doing something wrong here? Help from domain specialists would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The DFT implements cyclic convolution, not linear convolution.  You need a minimum amount of zero padding for cyclic convolution to coincide with linear convolution.  See chapter 9 of Orfanidis' book for details: https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/intro2sp/

Comment: Andy, that's why I added the link in my post indicating that fact. Using zero padding I am able to get the forward and inverse steps for convolution (in the time domain). Can you please share your thoughts as to how I would have to zero pad when doing the operations indicated above.

Comment: Well, your first $c_{fft}$ represents a cyclic convolution in the discrete frequency domain.  No amount of zero padding added to $a$ and $b$ will change that as their FFTs will be non-zero in almost every bin.  So, then for the other operations, your linear convolution of FFT(a) and FFT(b) will not match the circular convolution. Using the 'cconv()' function in MatLab, the circular convolution should come out properly though.

Comment: Andy, unfortunately I don't have Matlab. I was hoping a simple step-by-step explanation would be helpful not only for me but for others who may come here for this.